# MySQL Import Script Adding Extra Rows?

Tags: mysql

Hi i have written an import script for a merge I am currently doing. I am moving some data from one table to another and changing the values of some of the foreign keys hence the `LEFT JOINs` in the script.

When I run the script the table I am getting the data from contains 4,695,796 rows and after importing the data the new table has 4,861,376 (It was empty when I ran the import) and I have no idea why there are extra rows. That is an extra 150,000 rows.

Here is the script that I am running:

```
INSERT INTO `intelli_sense`.`wifi_daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour` (day_epoch, day_of_week, hour, venue_id, device_uuid, first_seen, last_seen, is_repeat, is_authorised, has_authorised, age, gender, postcode, provider)

SELECT day_epoch, day_of_week, hour, (CASE WHEN intelli_sense_venue.id!=0 THEN intelli_sense_venue.id ELSE 0 END), UNHEX(MD5(CONCAT(device.mac_address, device.venue_id))), summary_table.first_seen, summary_table.last_seen, is_repeat, is_authorised, has_authorised, age, gender, postcode, provider
FROM wifi.daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour AS summary_table
LEFT JOIN wifi.venue AS wifi_venue_1 ON wifi_venue_1.id = summary_table.venue_id
LEFT JOIN intelli_sense.venue AS intelli_sense_venue ON intelli_sense_venue.name = wifi_venue_1.name
LEFT JOIN device AS device ON summary_table.device_uuid = device.device_uuid;
```

I wasn't sure if it was the joins which were causing the extra rows. All I want is to move the data from one table to another while changing the `venue_id` and `device_uuid`

I hope my explanation makes sense, I didn't go into detail of why I am doing the merge and when I need to change the values because I don't think that would help solve the problem. I am probably making a simple mistake but thank you in advance.

** ** EDIT ** **

I just tried running this script:

```
INSERT INTO `intelli_sense`.`wifi_daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour` (day_epoch, day_of_week, hour, venue_id, device_uuid, first_seen, last_seen, is_repeat, is_authorised, has_authorised, age, gender, postcode, provider)

SELECT day_epoch, day_of_week, hour, venue_id, summary_table.device_uuid, summary_table.first_seen, summary_table.last_seen, is_repeat, is_authorised, has_authorised, age, gender, postcode, provider
FROM wifi.daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour AS summary_table
```

So I removed all the joins and I still had 150,00 more rows which makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Are you sure that all referenced tables are referenced by unique identifiers? For example, by joining a n-n-relation-table, you could produce multiple rows

Comment: @NicoHaase Oh I didn't realise that, is there a way to get around it? I don't think device_uuid is unique in the device table so that join might be causing the issue. I will test it now.

Comment: @NicoHaase I just edited my question, I removed all the left joins and I still had 150,000 more rows.

Comment: How do you compute the number of rows? MySQL might only provide an estimated count, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151769/mysql-difference-between-using-count-and-information-schema-tables-for-coun

Comment: @NicoHaase That was the issue I was just using phpmyadmin which has the count at the top but that isn't correct. I just ran mysql code to get the count instead and they match... Thank you for thinking of this!

Comment: You're welcome. You could post this as an answer to help out people who are looking out for the same problem